# Width of control based on width of window

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, responsive-design

I'm trying to figure out, how to write Responsive UI in XAML.

I would like to have 2 controls on my window. MinWidth of each control id 400.

If Width of windows is >800, Width of each control should be 50%, if we change widht of window to <800, each control should have 100% of window.

It's pretty simple to set up something like that with HTML/CSS, and right now I'm trying do it in WPF without progress.

Can you help me with that?

I tried to handle that with WrapPanel, but it does not work. It wraps properly, but does not change width of control.

Comment: What if `Window.Width == 800`?

Answer (score 1):

I have two ideas for doing this:

1. Using a binding converter, and bind the width/height of each item to the container width/height.
2. Creating a custom panel, with de desired layout.

Only a few ideas, hope helps.

Answer (score 0):

- Define resources based on screen revolution.
- In design mode, using dynamic key to avoid errors.
- In runtime, dynamically add resources into App.